# How can I efficiently tell if a value I store is within a TypedArray's range?

Tags: javascript, typescript, integer-overflow

In Chrome (and likely other browsers), when I store a value to a TypedArray that is outside of its range, it is truncated:

```
const arr = new Uint16Array(1);
arr[0] = 100000;
console.log(arr[0]); // logs 34464
```

I have a design where I can allow a user to supply any TypedArray type, and I would like to be able to detect when this overflow would happen and throw a RangeError instead of allowing the data to be truncated:

```
const arr: T = getArraySomehow(); // T implements TypedArray
const val: number = getValueSomehow();
if (valOverflows(val, arr)) {
    throw new RangeError('Value overflow');
}
arr[getIndexSomehow()] = val;
```

What's the best way to implement/inline `valOverflows()`?

- Should I actually try storing the value and see if I get it back unaltered? This probably works for integer arrays, but not float arrays (since the loss here would likely just be a loss of precision), and other methods might be faster.
- Is there a secret/experimental method on the `TypedArray` prototype that give minimum and maximum values, or a flag that causes overflows to be signaled?
- Should I just use `instanceof` checks and some kind of lookup table?

Comment: The best I know would involve `BYTES_PER_ELEMENT`, but it doesn't allow checking for signed vs unsigned elements. Barring just writing to the array, I think a lookup table (`Map`) would probably the most appropriate solution.

Comment: Your design is a bit weird. Why do you not know the range of the values that you are going to store beforehand, why do you allow the user to pass arbitrary array types? I would suggest that a caller of your function should pass the `valOverflows` function alongside the array, have them be responsible for both. Use `() => false` as a fallback if they don't provide a check function.

Answer (score 1):

I like your first idea (have you tried it?).

```js
const compare = (val, type) => {
  const arr = new type(1)
  arr[0] = val
  const same = arr[0] === val
  console.log(val, arr[0], same)
  return same
}

var value = 300
compare(value, Int16Array)
compare(value, Uint8Array)
compare(value, Uint16Array)
value = 2**32
compare(value, Uint32Array)
value -= 1
compare(value, Uint32Array)
```

This simply compares the value with an instance of the value set on a particular array type.

---

Now as you mentioned this won't work for floats, as the value might well be in the range, just have issues with precision. For floats you could use a map and compare hardcoded range limits. But I guess if you do that, you may as well use a map for all types.

```js
const ranges = {
  [Uint8Array.name]: {
    min: 0,
    max: 255
  },
  [Float32Array.name]: {
    min: 1.2e-38,
    max: 3.4e38
  }
}

const compare = (val, type) => {
  const { min, max } = ranges[type.name]
  return val >= min && val <= max
}

console.log(compare(100, Float32Array))
console.log(compare(3.4e38, Float32Array))
console.log(compare(3.5e38, Float32Array))
console.log(compare(255, Uint8Array))
console.log(compare(256, Uint8Array))
```

The ranges can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray